# There will be vs There is : When writing proposals for IT projects

Tags: technical-writing, tenses

Please read following two sentence.

- There will be around 20 reports.
- There is around 20 reports.

What is the correct / most suitable one?

Comment: Seeing how there's more than one report I think it should be "There are around 20 reports" rather than "There is around 20 reports"

Comment: Are you asking which tense to use in describing requirements? There is a fairly formal language for the description of formal requirements. If that is what you are looking for, please clarify. Until then I am placing this on hold as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether the reports have been written or delivered. If this hasn't yet happened, the first is correct.

The second is wrong either way, since you have a singular "is" with a plural "reports". If reports have already been written, "there are around 20 reports" would be correct - but if so, can you be more accurate than "around 20"? Eighteen? Twenty one?

Do reports already exist? If so, the present tense is more accurate than the future tense. This is no different in technical writing to any other kind.

Comment: No, reports is not exit because this is a just proposal. So I will use There will be around 20 reports. Thanks for showing my mistakes also.

Comment: It sounds like that would be right for the proposal. If you know at this point precisely how many reports there will be it would be good to include that, but I understand you might not know or might want to be less specific at this point.